# setClass error when using "initialize" method and slots attribute

Tags: r

Based [setClass](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/methods/html/setClass.html) documentation, the argument `representation`is deprecated and its recommended to use the special method: "initialize". I am getting the following error:

```
   Error in setClass("Person", slots = c(name = "character", address = "character",  : 
  Argument "representation" cannot be used if argument "slots" is supplied
```

For this simple class:

```
setClass("Person",
     slots =c(name = "character", address = "character", phone = "character"),
     setMethod("initialize",
       "Person",
       definition=function(.Object, aName = character(0), aAddress = character(0), 
         aPhone=character(0)) {
           .Object@name <- aNname
           .Object@address <- aAddress
           .Object@phone <- aPhone
           .Object
       }
     )
)
```

was of trying other options, but I get always an error. For sure I am missing something.

**EDIT** (Based on @Sathish solution)

How to define additional methods?, for example `setName`:

```
setClass(Class = "Person",
    slots = representation(name = "character", address = "character", phone = "character"),
    setMethod(f = "setName", signature = c("character"),
        definition = function(.Object, aName) {
        .Object@name <- aName
    })
)
```

I understand it has to be defined inside the class definition, because in the `setMethod` I don't see how to link the method with the class, the `signature` according to [setMethod](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/setMethod.html) documentation, is for the argument definition. I get the same error.

1. *Is this the correct way to use the object itself (special `this` notation in other languages, here seems to be `.Object` notation)?*. Perhaps I come from the java-mind set and I don't get the idea of OO under R.
2. *Is it a good practice to define accesor methods, such as:get/set, or just use the `@`- syntax?*: `person@name <- aName` for `set` method, or `person@name` for get method, where `person` is an instance of class `Person`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `c` and `representation` does the same thing, that is creating a named vector for Class representation.

`representation()` is an utility function used to create named vector with values as data types. It is used for backward compatibility with `representation` argument

`c()` can be used to create named vector for `slots`, but not for `representation` argument. But using `list()` will work for both `slots` and `representation` arguments. See examples below.

```
# create a class 'Person'
# with slots argument and representation() function
setClass(Class = "Person",
         slots = representation( name = "character", address = "character", phone = "character"))
getClass('Person')
removeClass('Person')

# with slots argument and c() function
setClass(Class = "Person",
         slots = c( name = "character", address = "character", phone = "character"))
getClass('Person')
removeClass('Person')

# with representation argument and representation() function
setClass(Class = "Person",
         representation = representation( name = "character", address = "character", phone = "character"))
getClass('Person')
removeClass('Person')

# with representation argument and c() function
setClass(Class = "Person",
         representation = c( name = "character", address = "character", phone = "character"))
# Error in validObject(.Object) : 
#   invalid class “classRepresentation” object: invalid object for slot "slots" in class "classRepresentation": got class "character", should be or extend class "list"

getClass('Person')
# Error in getClass("Person") : “Person” is not a defined class

# with list()
setClass(Class = "Person",
         representation = list( name = "character", address = "character", phone = "character") )
getClass('Person')
removeClass('Person')

setClass(Class = "Person",
         slots = list( name = "character", address = "character", phone = "character") )
getClass('Person')
removeClass('Person')

# initialize method during object instantiation
setMethod(f = "initialize", signature = "Person",
          definition = function( .Object, Aname, Aaddress, Aphone) 
          { 
            .Object@name    <- Aname
            .Object@address <- Aaddress
            .Object@phone   <- Aphone
            return( .Object )
          } )
```

Methods are declared and assigned or removed to and from generic functions through calls to `setMethod` or `removeMethod(s)`

```
# getters and setters
# reserve the name of the method by using setGeneric() and standardGeneric()
setGeneric( name = "getName", signature = 'obj', def  = function( obj ) standardGeneric( "getName" ))       # "getName"
setGeneric( name = "setName", signature = 'obj', def  = function( obj, name ) standardGeneric( "setName" )) # "setName"

# set the reserved method getName | setName to Person Class
setMethod( f = "getName", signature = "Person", definition = function( obj ) return( obj@name ))                         # "getName"
setMethod( f = "setName", signature = "Person", definition = function( obj, name ) { obj@name <- name; return( obj ) } ) # "setName"

showMethods('getName')
# Function: getName (package .GlobalEnv)
# obj="Person"

showMethods('setName')
# Function: setName (package .GlobalEnv)
# obj="Person"

# create new instance of the class 'Person' using new()
myobj <- new(Class = "Person", Aname = "bob", Aaddress = "xxxx", Aphone = "243-344-3434")

myobj
# An object of class "Person"
# Slot "name":
#   [1] "bob"
# 
# Slot "address":
#   [1] "xxxx"
# 
# Slot "phone":
#   [1] "243-344-3434"

getName( myobj )
# [1] "bob"

myobj <- setName( myobj, 'bill')
getName( myobj )
# [1] "bill"
```

clean up classes and methods

```
removeMethod('getName', signature = 'Person')
# [1] TRUE
removeMethod('setName', signature = 'Person')
# [1] TRUE
removeClass('Person')
# [1] TRUE
removeGeneric('getName')
# [1] TRUE
removeGeneric('setName')
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works but the R-syntax for OO is really confusing  for me. What is the different when using `c()` and `representation()` for attribute `representation`. Both are valid, and I get the same result after `getClass("Person")`. How can I define an a getter method (setName for example, I don't know it is really necessary in R)? I get a compilation error when I try to define it. I will update the question for more clarify.

Comment: Thanks it work!, then it is not like in classical OO language, in R we don't have `.` notation or equivalent. Under R invoking a getter will be: `getName(myobj)`, not `myobj.getName()` neither `myobj$getName(), myobj@getName()`

Comment: Historically, R has about 9 different forms of OO implemented in base R and through packages. Features from other languages are implemented in different forms of OO in R. Read `Extending R` book by John Chambers

Comment: based on your OO introduction and feedback I created a documentation example, about how to [apply S4 classes for defining a parser using state machine](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/9126/implement-state-machine-pattern-using-s4-class). any feedback is welcome.

Comment: @DavidLeal I will take a look at it when I get time. Mean while, I upvoted it. Thanks for the info